# Reversing string lines

Tags: c#, string

How can I reverse string lines? Not a text file.
String tekstGecmis is : "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n"

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

To:

> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1

I tried

```
string son = String.Empty;
StringBuilder ters = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    string[] lines = tekstGecmis.Split('\r','\n');
    string last_line = lines[lines.Length - i];
    
    ters.AppendLine(son + last_line);
    
    son = ters.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Change this part `tekstGecmis.Split('\r','\n');`

Comment: There are plenty of questions and documentation about reversing lists/arrays/... - when asking questions author is expected to demonstrate what they found researching the solution and how it did not work in they case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will turn "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n" into "3\r\n2\r\n1\r\n", which is what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
str = string.Join("\r\n",
    str.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted. .

Comment: I m using on my xamarin portable project. While on uwp platform is everything ok on Android platform doesnt work. Is it possible Android is using something else for new line( \r\n) ?

Comment: @YasarCurci It's possible. You can use `Environment.NewLine` instead. It's probably just `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
string text = "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n";

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", text.Split('\r','\n').Reverse()));
```

[working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OoQEFB)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Reverse` and `string.Join` methods. Like this:

```
string result = string.Join("",son.Reverse());
```

Result:

> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1

Comment: If it has line with `length>1` your code will reverse the line. For example 31 changes to 13

Comment: It reverse also 123 line to 321. I want lines to stay same. Thanks

Comment: @YasarCurci So you need to place this code after `string[] lines = tekstGecmis.Split('\r','\n');` line and replace the `son` with `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string str1 = "1\r\n12\r\n31";
        string[] lines = str1.Split(new char[]{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        lines = lines.Reverse().ToArray();
        string result = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Split` the `string` before the cycle
2. Inverse the cycle's direction
3. Calculate `ters` after the cycle

`string son = String.Empty;
StringBuilder ters = new StringBuilder();
string[] lines = tekstGecmis.Split('\r','\n');
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ters.AppendLine(lines[i]);
}
son = ters.ToString();`